# Scrollable part of the page with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page structured with bootstrap, in this page i have a row with content at the top, then another row divided into col-lg-3, col-lg-6, col-lg-3. 
What i want is when i reach the second row after scrolling down to it to make the col-lg-3 (both of them) fixed and to make only the col-lg-6 scrollable, i tried setting there position to fixed but it didn't work, how can i do that? Here is my code:

```css
.greydiv {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 450px;
}

.blackdiv {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 800px;
}

.greendiv {
  background-color: #080;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <p>Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
    <div class="greydiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="blackdiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
    <div class="greendiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: have you fixed this ?

Comment: @edisoni.1337 not yet, any suggestions?

Comment: Just let me check once @jessica

Comment: You mean something like this @jessica ? https://jsfiddle.net/tnw586h4/13/

Comment: @edisoni.1337 yes! but the col-lg-3 divs should stay at the top why are they at the bottom?

Comment: to be honnest i didn't tried it so i will fix that

Comment: The CSS specification requires that position:fixed be anchored to the viewport, not the containing positioned element so you need to specify it using javascript or giving a `top` value manualy

Comment: @edisoni.1337 okay i get it now, than you, can you post this an answer? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149243/discussion-between-edisoni-1337-and-jessica).

Comment: check your chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get with javascript when user has reached second row while scrolling.

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= $('.greydiv').offset().top ) {
         // we add a class fixed to col-lg-3 children
         $('.col-lg-3 div').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

The next thing is to add our css style for fixed `class`

```
.fixed{
      position:fixed!important;
      width: inherit;
}
```

The width should be inherit so it gets parent width.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your request right, so:

You can fix these 2 elements when they hit the top of your browser via jQuery:

```
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= $('.greydiv').offset().top ) {
         // div has reached the top
         $('.greydiv').addClass('someFixedClass');
    }
});
```

Then you have to style `.someFixedClass` with something like `position:fixed`

Comment: what about the reverse?

Comment: @charlietfl add `else` and than use `removeClass()` instead of `addClass()`

Comment: I wasn't asking for myself... just mentioning it's not part of the solution in your answer

Comment: @JaxCze can you explain to me what does this function do please?